# Manga where a retired knight goes to a village where summoned heroes reside

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's about a knight who retires and goes back to the village. He then realises that the village has summoned heroes residing there. All heroes have different abilities like super strength, medical abilities, etc. It is more of a slice of life kind of manga. I just don't know the name of that manga

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) for good manga ID questions, to see if you can [edit] any more details into your question.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

This is *[The Suffering of Local Knight Hans](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/chihou-kishi-hans-no-junan)*, aka *Chihou Kishi Hans no Junan*

> Sick of the trickery in the royal court, former knight captain Hans now serves at a remote station in the countryside. But his peaceful and idyllic days end when some Japanese people with superhuman abilities suddenly show up.

The synopsis pretty much matches everything in the question. The summoned heroes have various abilities, and super strength was definitely one of them. It's been a while since I read it so I don't remember the specifics of the abilities.