# Manga where the main character is a soldier sent out to the countryside but isekai people keep showing up

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I've been trying to find this manga for a while after the site I was reading it on got taken down, and I can't remember what it's called for the life of me.

The main character is a native of this fantasy kingdom; he used to be either a knight or a royal guard or something, but was moved out to the countryside (I think for political reasons). However, he keeps finding people that got isekai'd into his world near the village he guards. There's this healer guy, and this girl that has what I think was super strength or something similar, and there was a guy who was a monster tamer who starts up a ranch and I remember him super clearly because he had this big pompadour or some kinda weird hairdo similar to that.

It starts off very "village upgrade through isekai knowledge" in a way, but then this whole plot with another country or territory or something begins and then I lost the manga before it resolved and now I keep remembering it super vaguely at least once a week.

Comment: Please accept the correct answer instead of editing that into your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is *[The Ordeals of Regional Knight Hans](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-ordeals-of-regional-knight-hans)*, aka *Chihou Kishi Hans no Junan*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255031).

> Former exemplary knight Hans was transferred to a **small knight station in a rural town**. Despite his many achievements, he hated the hustle and bustle of the imperial capital, and he was enjoying his quiet and peaceful life at his regional knight station. Then one day, **Japanese people with superhuman abilities suddenly appeared from another world**...! Former exemplary knight Hans is at the mercy of unbelievable Japanese people in this isekai knight station fantasy!

Synopsis is a solid match for the question. Hans is forced out of the capital to a rural area, which suits him just fine. Japanese people start showing up, and later on also at least one person from the capital who went to see him.

It's been a while since I read it but I do distinctly recall a young girl with super strength, and an old yakuza boss who gets healed and becomes much younger.

Comment: YES! THAT'S IT!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: @JacobSalego You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).